# Best way to implement HTML5 isometric game?

Tags: html, canvas, webgl, isometric

What would you say, using canvas or webGL?

I have read somewhere that canvas isn't very performant, because currently it's based on the DOM, or something like that. On the other side webGL isn't well supported yet. And it's also more difficult to learn I guess.

The game is "2.5"D - it doesn't need 3D. But wegGL could make sense for good effects and because it's processed in the graphics card. The fact that it is not well supported across browsers is something I could live with, if I see it really offers advantages (performance, effects, etc.) which I couldn't get using canvas.

I don't mind about steeper learning curve. What is important is that the game is well scalable, performs well at the end, and that most features are potentially possible.

Hope to get some good opinions, thanks in advance!

Comment: canvas is still rather slow on mobile when you redraw large portions - you might consider using css3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2D Canvas will do you well here.

The math will be far easier than using WebGL and 2D Canvas is now hardware accelerated on every major desktop browser and enjoys wider support on mobile devices than WebGL.

Canvas is not slow because its a DOM element, ideally the only time you touch the DOM is when you get the context. Touching the DOM, for the record, is always slow but you only *have* to do it that one time.

There are a few tutorials about isometric canvas games as well as some good questions here on StackOverflow asked by Neurofluxation, but he deleted most of the relevant code from his questions for some reason, which is a bit of a shame.